# Get the URL of current script even if it's included?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that needs to know it's URL, even if it's included within another script.  I've tried:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

But this doesn't return the URI to my script--rather, it returns the URI to the *including* script.  I've also tried:

```
dirname ( __FILE__ )
```

But I can't seem to convert this to an absolute URL.

Can my script find its own URL, even if it's being included in another script?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Short answer is NO. Long answer is also NO

Comment: Exactly why do you need to know its location?

Comment: It's a reusable module that writes HTML to a page, including URL references to itself for AJAX.  I can hard-code its location, but I was hoping for a way to get it programmatically.

Comment: You could maybe try comparing __FILE__ against argv[0] and whatnot, but there really is no reliable way of detecting if a script was included()'d or directly executed. That's the whole point of include() - it's supposed to be transparent to the code.

Comment: Surely all you need to know is the URL from $_SERVER even if the script is included when that url is called then your script is still run, which is what it sounds like you need. Rather than trying to call a possibly included file directly which I would certainly frown on as it bypasses all the rest of the application configuration and logic.

Comment: @Anigel -- Actually, this is a module of scripts which can be used by other scripts.  This module needs to generate URLs that map to various scripts within the module for AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't, at least not in a robust and portable way. PHP encourages developers to think that the URL maps directly with a script, so one may be convinced that for each script S there's a *function(S)* which gives its public URL.

Unfortunately, this is not true. As a quick reference, just think of `mod_rewrite` or the chance that your script may be requested by a reverse proxy.

If you really need this functionality, it could be that you have a design mistake, so if you tell what your problem is exactly (in terms of functionality, not implementation) someone may come up with the right solution for you.

Comment: Thanks.  My module writes HTML forms to a webpage, and it has to reference itself using URLs for AJAX.  The URLs can't be relative because the location of the including script is unknown.

Comment: So just omit the `action` attribute in the `<form>` element: the user agent will default to the URL the page comes from