# Redirection from different path depths

Tags: php, redirect

In my project a file in PHP checks authentication.

$PROJECT_ROOT/lib/functions.php :

```
<?php
check_authentication();

function check_authentication(){
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }

        if(defined('authorized') && authorized){
                if(!(isset($_SESSION['admin'] && $_SESSION['admin']))){
                    header('Location: login.php');
                    exit(0);
                }
        }
}
```

The check_authentication function checks whether user has authenticated and if not it redirects to $PROJECT_ROOT/login.php page.

In file $PROJECT_ROOT/reader.php:

```
<?php
define('authorized',TRUE);

require_once('lib/functions.php');
```

This works OK!

However in file $PROJECT_ROOT/modules/text.php:

```
<?php
define('authorized',TRUE);

require_once('../lib/functions.php');
```

This is not redirecting correctly because it is **not located** in the $PROJECT_ROOT directory.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341786/get-the-url-of-current-script-even-if-its-included) I understand that it is not possible to obtain the URI folder of "functions.php".

However what can I do to solve this problem?

Obviously I can attempt to redirect with the absolute path but this it will hurt the portability of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the the $PROJECT_ROOT URL can not be referenced easily through PHP.

What is required is to create project URL abstraction relative to the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

This can be achieved in $PROJECT_ROOT/lib/functions.php :

```
define(PROJECT_URL,
       '//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
       substr(dirname(__DIR__), strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))
);
```

The starting '//' creates http/https protocol abstraction.

The above URL is constructed from these elements:

```
echo __DIR__;  // /var/www/html/project_x/service/lib (current script directory) 
echo '<br>';
echo dirname(__DIR__); // /var/www/html/project_x/service (the data model root directory in this case)
echo '<br>';
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // /var/www/html (prefix that need to be removed)
echo '<br>';
echo PROJECT_URL; // //localhost/project_x/service
```

The redirection now will occur with the absolute URL

```
header('Location: '.PROJECT_URL.'/login.php');
```